# Javascript Function not working in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

```
function showMe(id_show_element) {
    document.getElementById(id_show_element).style.display = '';
}
```

Comment: No, it's not. What question did you want us to answer for you?

Comment: sir, i am using this javascript function in my PHP page, but this function is not working properly in google chrome.
I want to show an element on select <option> from dropdown.

Comment: And how are you calling that function? And with what JavaScript? What's the (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    function showNhide(val,element_id) {    if(val == 'Others')    {    document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = '';    }    else    {    document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = 'none';    }    }    </script>




<select name="degrees" onchange="showNhide(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, 'others_details');">    <option value="">Select Degree</option>    <option value="O-Level">O-Level</option>    </select>    <span id="others_details" style="display:none">    <input type="text" name="others_degree" value="" />    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be other error in your javascript code, following is the example through which I hide the element:

```
    document.getElementById('dropdownListId').style.display = 'none';
```

to show this element I use following code

```
    document.getElementById('dropdownListId').style.display = '';
```

I think there is other javascript error in your code, please share small piece of code.